# Slack: MRU list?

Tags: slack

For chrome there is [quick tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-tabs/jnjfeinjfmenlddahdjdmgpbokiacbbb):

> A keyboard centric most recently used (MRU) ordered tab list plugin with search and switch functionality inspired by IntelliJ IDEA (like ctrl-e)

Feature in (for example) PyCharm: [Recent files list](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/guide/tips/recent-files/)

Is there a keyboard centric MRU channel list for slack?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something similar with <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> on Mac and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> on Windows.

You can find more information in the [official documentation](https://slack.com/intl/en-us/help/articles/201374536-Slack-keyboard-shortcuts).

Comment: Sorry, `ctrl-k` is not a most recently used list. Example: I am writing a direct message to Bob. During doing this, I get a message from Alice. I answer her question. Now I want to switch back to the direct message to Bob with a short-cut. `ctrl-k` is unfortunately not enough. I would really like to do this with **one** short-cut.

Comment: I understand what you are saying there, but `Cmd-K` is the closest you can get to an MRU list in the Slack world as of now.